# My terminal shows other's login information

Tags: debian, shell, terminal, console

I acturally asked the same topic on stack overflow and community said that is not suitable there. So I'll try to post it here.

I logged in my debian 12 server with Windows Terminal, and hang up there over an hour. When I come back, terminal shows some information about a hacker trying to connect my server.

It looks like below:

```
[root@debian 22:49 linux-6.6.7] #2023 Dec 15 22:58:26 debian fatal: Timeout before authentication for ***.***.***.*** port *****
2023 Dec 15 22:58:26 debian fatal: Timeout before authentication for ***.***.***.*** port *****
2023 Dec 15 22:58:26 debian fatal: Timeout before authentication for ***.***.***.*** port *****
2023 Dec 15 22:58:26 debian fatal: Timeout before authentication for ***.***.***.*** port *****
2023 Dec 15 22:58:27 debian fatal: Timeout before authentication for ***.***.***.*** port *****
2023 Dec 15 22:58:27 debian fatal: Timeout before authentication for ***.***.***.*** port *****
2023 Dec 15 22:58:27 debian fatal: Timeout before authentication for ***.***.***.*** port *****
2023 Dec 15 22:58:27 debian fatal: Timeout before authentication for ***.***.***.*** port *****
2023 Dec 15 22:58:27 debian fatal: Timeout before authentication for ***.***.***.*** port *****
2023 Dec 15 22:58:27 debian fatal: Timeout before authentication for ***.***.***.*** port *****
2023 Dec 15 22:58:28 debian fatal: Timeout before authentication for ***.***.***.*** port *****
2023 Dec 15 22:58:28 debian fatal: Timeout before authentication for ***.***.***.*** port *****
2023 Dec 15 22:58:28 debian fatal: Timeout before authentication for ***.***.***.*** port *****
```

Since I have installed fail2ban on my server and only use pubkey to access it, several attack can be dismiss. I just don't want to see these information in my console.
What should I do?

I searched google about 'console showing others login info' and variant, didn't get helpful information.

Comment: That might be because [`pam_lastlog`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_lastlog) is enabled with `showfailed` ; or syslog / rsyslog having been configured to direct certain message  on the terminals of all/specific  currently logged in users https://rsyslog-doc-v5.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/modules/omusrmsg.html

Comment: Where sending security notifications to specifically to the root user makes sense

Comment: I checked my /etc/pam.d/login file and `pam_lastlog` has no extra setting. So was syslog/ rsyslog. I dont think I acturally modified these files or configurations. Now I'm trying to modify `pam_lastlog` as `silent`. See anything changes.